# Javascript/jquery function is calculating the result of my parameter even though it is a string?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

So I have a PHP variable called `$startDate` which is a string and contains something like `2020-01-13`. I am passing this to a javascript function like so `<button onclick="loaddevs(<?= $startDate ?>)"></button>`

At some point in this function, I am sending the variable to a PHP script by:

```
function loaddevs(startDate) {
........
........

$("#developerTeamColumn").load("testing.php", { date: startDate }, function() {
    init();
});
}
```

My problem is that javascript is treating the string as an expression and sending, in the case of my example, '2006' to the script. How do I prevent this?

Comment: Put quotes around the parameter: `onclick="loaddevs('<?= $startDate ?>')"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When rendering something in PHP, the quotes around a string are not included. You need to explicitly include them:

```
<button onclick="loaddevs('<?= $startDate ?>')"></button>

or

<button onclick="loaddevs(<?= "'$startDate'" ?>)"></button>
```